# Density of Ramsey subsets of $\omega$

Tags: measure-theory, infinite-combinatorics, ramsey-theory

For any set $X$ let $[X]^2=\{\{x,y\}:x\neq y \in X\}$. The starting point of this question is the following statement that follows from a more general theorem by Ramsey:

> If $\pi:[\omega]^2\to\{0,1\}$ is any map, then here is an infinite set $S\subseteq \omega$ such that the restriction $\pi|_{[S]^2}$ is constant.

We call an infinite set $S$ with the above property a *Ramsey set* for the map $\pi:[\omega]^2\to\{0,1\}$. For $A\subseteq \omega$ we define its upper density $d(A)\in [0,1]$ by $$d(A) = \lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|}{n}.$$

**Question.** Given a map $\pi:[\omega]^2\to\{0,1\}$, is there necessarily a Ramsey set $S\subseteq \omega$ with $d(S)>0$?

Comment: It is worth mentioning the following result of Erdos and Galvin: in a coloring $f:[\omega]^2\to\{0,1,2\}$ there is an infinite set containing at least $c\log n$ elements below $n$ and spanning only 2 colors. Erdos, Galvin: Some Ramsey type theorems, Disc. Math., 87(1991), 261-269.

Comment: @PéterKomjáth The set can't possibly contain "at least $c\log n$ elements below $n$" for **all** $n$. What is the correct statement? Is it something like "at least $c\log n$ elements below $n$ for infinitely many $n$"? But the set of $n$ for which that holds can be arbitrarily sparse?

Comment: To see that "the set of $n$ for which that holds can be arbitrarily sparse" consider a partition of $\omega$ into intervals $I_1\lt I_2\lt\cdots$ of rapidly increasing length and let $f(\{x,y\})=i\in\{0,1,2\}$ if $x,y\in I_{3m+i}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Decompose $\omega$ into the disjoint union of the sets $I_k$ where $I_k=[k!,(k+1)!-1]$. Let $f(x,y)$ be 1 if $x,y$ are in distinct intervals, otherwise 0. It is easy to see that each homogeneous set for 1 is finite, for 0 has zero density.

Comment: Thank you for this beautiful and easy to understand example!

Answer (score 6):

If we define $\pi: [\mathbb N]^2 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ randomly (say each $\pi(a,b)$ is determined by a coin flip), then almost surely there is no set $S$ with $d(S) > 0$ that is Ramsey for $\pi$. In fact, it is almost surely true that every $S$ with $d(S) > 0$ contains an induced isomorphic copy of the randomly colored infinite graph.

Even more: for a random coloring $\pi$ of $[\mathbb N]^2$, there is almost surely no set $S$ with $\sum_{n  \in S \setminus \{0\}} \frac{1}{n} = \infty$ that is Ramsey for $\pi$. In fact, it is almost surely true that every such $S$ contains an induced copy of every coloring of every finite graph. (But in this case, "finite" cannot be improved to "infinite" as above.)

These results can be found in Section 2 of my paper "Which subsets of the infinite random graph look random?" (*Mathematical Logic Quarterly* **64** (2018), pp. 478-486), available [here](https://wrbrian.files.wordpress.com/2018/05/randomgraphs2.pdf).

Comment: Thanks both of you for the beautiful answers - I wish I could accept both!